# Define php variables that contain both HTML and subsequently, dynamically settable variables for use later in script?

Tags: php, html, pass-by-reference, scope

I'm wondering if I want to do may not be possible... My PHP code loops through jpgs and flv files in an image directory and generates content that consists of in some instances HTML, in others CSS combined with dynamically determined values, for example:

```
'ul.set li.'.$className.
'{background: url(imagessmall/'.$fileName.') 
left -2px no-repeat;}'
```

Since the above (and much longer sections of HTML+variables) occurs more than once in the code, and because it would make the code easier to review and maintain, I'd like to be able to separate out these html + $variable by defining a set of variables up front, then reference them as needed, for example:

```
$SDImagePreview = 
     'ul.set li.'.$className. 
    '{background: url(imagessmall/'.$fileName.') 
     left -2px no-repeat;}'
             .
             .
             .
//Code that dynamically sets $className and $fileName is here

$write = fwrite($fileCSS, $SDImagePreview);
```

I've read on stackoverflow and elsewhere about using &, as in &$fieldName to pass values by reference, but haven't found examples of defining a variable that has *within* it a variable whose value can be set dynamically.

Am I trying to do something that is just not doable? Or are there alternate suggestions re: implementing the general approach I'm describing? Thanks for any suggestions.

Rather than embedding the html in the code itself, I'd like to be able to define a set of variables at the start of the code, then reference them as needed,

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but here's a tip. You can do variable variables, for example $fruit = 'apple'; $$fruit = 'orange'; echo $apple; // returns orange

Comment: That doesn't look like HTML, it's CSS. Not that this matters for your question. Functions are the way to go, as GGG said.

Comment: What you are asking is entirely doable, and is called a template engine.  I recommend looking at the ones already available before trying to build your own.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, GGG didn't exactly *say*, use functions and here are some friendly tips on how to think about it :-), just cryptically dropped in a link... But I did restructure code into a couple functions, which tidied things nicely...By the way, we're neighbors! Hello...

Comment: @Jason thanks for the information. Wasn't applicable to this issue - at least not from the bit of experimenting I did - but is useful to know about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible you just have to put your CSS directly to your code in the  just add :

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
(...) you generate CSS
<?php print $SDImagePreview; ?>
</style>
```

CSS are most faster to load if is an extarnal .css file for the caching but in your case the CSS need to be generated in PHP so no cache can be done. If you want to have this change the CSS rule already define by other .css file juste put it after.